# Extract a value that passed the truth test in a Parse Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

**Issue**

i saved an array of 2 users in parse , i want to extract in the array only the one who pass the truth test , only the one who is not equal to the current value of parse.User. this is what i'm doing

```js
Array.find(function(e){
  return e.id != Parse.User.current().id
})
```

Doing this return me an undefined value

this is how i'm saving the array

```js
function createRooms(){
 var chatRooms = new ChatRooms();
 var userOne = Parse.User.current()
 var userTwo = AchatsDetailsData.value.seller
 var chateur = [userOne, userTwo]
 chatRooms.set("lastMessages", "undefined");
 chatRooms.set("Users", chateur);
 chatRooms.save().then(function(results){
  console.log("created")
  goToChatDetails()
 }, function(error){

 })
}
```

this is how i'm loading the data.

```js
function loadrooms(){
 var roomsQuery = new Parse.Query("ChatRooms")
 roomsQuery.equalTo("Users", Parse.User.current())
 roomsQuery.notEqualTo("lastMessages", "undefined")
 roomsQuery.descending("updatedAt")
 roomsQuery.find().then(function(results){
  roomsAll.refreshAll(results,
   function(oldItem, newItem){
   return oldItem.id == newItem.id;
  },
  function(oldItem, newItem){
   oldItem.time == newItem.get("updatedAt");
  },
  function(newItem){
   return new Rooms(newItem.id, newItem.get("lastMessages"), newItem.get("Users"), newItem.get("updatedAt"), newItem)
  }
  )
 })
}

function Rooms(id, lastmessage, user, time, parsObject){
 var self = this;
 this.id = id;
 this.lastmessage = lastmessage;
 this.user = user.find(function(e){
  return e.id != Parse.User.current().id
 })
 this.RigID = this.user.get("RigID");
 this.time = time;
 this.userName = this.user.get("nom") + " " + this.user.get("prenom")
 this.parsObject = parsObject;
 this.userpicture = this.user.get("photo");
 this.pics = Observable(function(){
  if(this.userpicture == null){
   return "http://az664292.vo.msecnd.net/files/B2MmOFAy2wjpUo71-model-045.jpg"
  }else{
   return this.userpicture
  }
 })
}
```

so i have 2 users in the array chateur when i click to createRooms function, i want to extract the user who is not equal to the current user for displaying my chat room

Comment: Is your *"array of 2 users"* really named `Array`?

Comment: can you share your array definition?

Comment: i updated my code , @Phil no this was just for explaining my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly , i just forget to include my Users array into the query

`roomsQuery.include("Users")`